# Expo eject not working - cannot use react-link

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

To recreate this project do  - Create a react-native project with Expo

```
npm install -g expo-cli
expo init AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject
npm start
```

then

```
expo eject
```

I'm trying to use this project with

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker

How do I make it work? I've tried everything but I have no clue right now.

I get the following error

On click of a button to open ImagePicker.showImagePicker I get the error

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating ImagePickerManager.showImagePicker').
```

I am on Windows.

Comment: https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/sdk/imagepicker .  Expo comes with ImagePicker

Comment: Oh wow, it works. Lol. Thanks!